# Dynamically init an instance with ES6 JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to init an object dynamically with ES6 class?

```
class AnObject{
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
   }
}
let p1 = new AnObject("name1");
console.log("p1 name: " + p1.name);
var className = "An" + "Object";
let p2 = new className("name2"); // Dynamically init an object?
console.log("p2 name: " + p2.name);
```

Comment: It's no different than in ES5 - `AnObject` is just a function, and you have to get that function by its name before calling `new`. Using ES6 syntax for the class makes zero difference.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, this is probably a duplicate. Although there is *one very slight* difference: If you're at global scope, you can't use the class from the global object, because class identifiers at global scope aren't added to the global object, even though they're global variables. (As with `let` and `const` at global scope.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to put your constructors on an object, and then look them up on that object using the generated string key:

```
let ctors = {
    AnObject: class {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
};

let className = "An" + "Object";
let p2 = new ctors[className]("name2");
console.log("p2 name: " + p2.name);
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20ctors%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20AnObject%3A%20class%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20className%20%3D%20%22An%22%20%2B%20%22Object%22%3B%0Alet%20p2%20%3D%20new%20ctors%5BclassName%5D(%22name2%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22p2%20name%3A%20%22%20%2B%20p2.name)%3B%0A)

---

Alternately, and I'm just being complete here **not recommending** it, you can use `eval`:

```
class AnObject {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
let className = "An" + "Object";
let p2 = new (eval(className))("name2");
console.log("p2 name: " + p2.name)
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20AnObject%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20className%20%3D%20%22An%22%20%2B%20%22Object%22%3B%0Alet%20p2%20%3D%20new%20(eval(className))(%22name2%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22p2%20name%3A%20%22%20%2B%20p2.name)%3B)

Or a bit more verbose, but possibly clearer:

```
let className = "An" + "Object";
let ctor = eval(className);
let p2 = new ctor("name2");
console.log("p2 name: " + p2.name)
```

`eval` is fine as long as you're in complete control of the strings you're evaluating. But it's usually overkill in well-structured code.